# Iterate specific files in directory via .bat

Tags: windows, batch-file, console

I try to create bat file to iterate throuth only files in directory which file names begin with specific word. 
For Example:
**companyName**.module1.exe 
**companyName**.module2.dll

I know how to iterate files but don't know how to check their names for specific condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following to your batch file:

```
for /F "eol=: tokens=*" %%A in ('dir /A-D /B "companyName*"') do (echo %%~fA)
```

This script will `echo` all files (files only) that begin with **companyName** prefix in the current working directory. Replace `echo` with any other command or commands that you want to perform instead.

**Update 1**: In order to look in a different directory you can either

```
for /F "eol=: tokens=*" %%A in ('dir /A-D /B "pathToLookIn/companyName*"') do (echo %%~fA)
```

or

```
pushd \ & cd "pathToLookIn" & (for /F "eol=: tokens=*" %%A in ('dir /A-D /B "companyName*"') do (echo %%~fA)) & popd
```

Where **pathToLookIn** is a fully qualified or relative path.

**Update 2**: I've updated the `for /F` loop to handle file names that begin with `;` as @dbenham suggested.

Comment: Your code works perfectly but when i want to use specific directory it takes all files. I use next command
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%A in ('dir /B "Company*" /b D:\DLLS\current') do (ECHO %%A)
Where is mistake?

Comment: how to change current working directory to specific directory?

Comment: I am Already find the answer. I changed current directory with CD command. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: @Polaris You will probably never have a problem, but technically a file name can begin with `;`, in which case it will be skipped because of default FOR /F EOL option. Use `FOR /F "eol=: tokens=*"` or `FOR /F "eol=: delims="` instead. This works because a valid Windows path (or file name) can never start with `:`.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you know how to iterate files, then just use that knowledge:

```
for %%f in (companyName*) do (
  ...
)
```

Note that iterating over the output of `dir` is error-prone and will mangle Unicode characters in many cases. Since `for` is capable of iteration directly there's rarely a need to use a inferior option.

Comment: You beat me to it by seconds :) FOR /F ... ('DIR ...') is only needed if the DO clause modifies the directory listing. The simple FOR statement is indeterminant - it may or may not see the changes. The FOR /F version buffers the output of the DIR before processing the DO clause, so it will always be insulated from any changes.

Comment: Ah, thanks for the note. That's a restriction I never thought about, but I encounter the Unicode one (with Raster fonts) pretty often.